# How to Force an Exception from a Task to be Observed in a Continuation Task?

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-extensions

I have a task to perform an `HttpWebRequest` using

```
 Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(req.BeginGetRespone, req.EndGetResponse)
```

which can obviously fail with a `WebException`. To the caller I want to return a `Task<HttpResult>` where `HttpResult` is a helper type to encapsulate the response (or not). In this case a 4xx or 5xx response is *not* an exception.

Therefore I've attached two continuations to the request task. One with `TaskContinuationOptions` `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` and the other with `OnlyOnOnFaulted`. And then wrapped the whole thing in a `Task<HttpResult>` to pick up the one result whichever continuation completes.

Each of the three child tasks (request plus two continuations) is created with the `AttachedToParent` option.

But when the caller waits on the returned outer task, an `AggregateException` is thrown is the request failed.

I want to, in the on faulted continuation, observe the `WebException` so the client code can just look at the result. Adding a `Wait` in the on fault continuation throws, but a try-catch around this doesn't help. Nor does looking at the `Exception` property (as section "Observing Exceptions By Using the Task.Exception Property" hints [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(VS.100).aspx)).

I could install a `UnobservedTaskException` event handler to filter, but as the event offers no direct link to the faulted task this will likely interact outside this part of the application and is a case of a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Given an instance of a faulted `Task<T>` is there any means of flagging it as "fault handled"?

Simplified code:

```
public static Task<HttpResult> Start(Uri url) {
    var webReq = BuildHttpWebRequest(url);
    var result = new HttpResult();
    var taskOuter = Task<HttpResult>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var tRequest = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                            webReq.BeginGetResponse,
                            webReq.EndGetResponse,
                            null, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        var tError = tRequest.ContinueWith<HttpResult>(
                            t => HandleWebRequestError(t, result),
                            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent
                            |TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        var tSuccess = tRequest.ContinueWith<HttpResult>(
                            t => HandleWebRequestSuccess(t, result),
                            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent
                            |TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        return result;
    });

    return taskOuter;
}
```

with:

```
private static HttpDownloaderResult HandleWebRequestError(
                                        Task<WebResponse> respTask, 
                                        HttpResult result) {
    Debug.Assert(respTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted);
    Debug.Assert(respTask.Exception.InnerException is WebException);
    // Try and observe the fault: Doesn't help.
    try {
        respTask.Wait();
    } catch (AggregateException e) {
        Log("HandleWebRequestError: waiting on antecedent task threw inner: "
             + e.InnerException.Message);
    }
    // ... populate result with details of the failure for the client ...
    return result;
}
```

(`HandleWebRequestSuccess` will eventually spin off further tasks to get the content of the response...)

The client should be able to wait on the task and then look at its result, without it throwing due to a fault that is expected and already handled.

Comment: `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` isn't being fired, even with most (if not all) of the places `AggregateException` would be thrown removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I took the simplest route I could think of: hide the exception. This is possible because `WebException` has a property `Response` which gives access to the `HttpWebResponse` I want:

```
var requestTask = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                        webReq.BeginGetResponse,
                        ia => {
                          try {
                            return webReq.EndGetResponse(ia);
                          } catch (WebException exn) {
                            requestState.Log(...);
                            return exn.Response;
                          }
                        });
```

And then handle errors, redirects and success responses in the continuation task.